A DBI backend for my switch as a practice
I have not been writing c++, but I wanted to practice something since my next project at work will require me to use it again. So I wrote a dpi backend in c++ for the Nintendo switch.
I split the functionality into 2 classes. The first class is for the USB-Communication:
My header file:
#ifndef USBCONTEXT_H
#define USBCONTEXT_H

#include <libusb.h>

class UsbContext {
    private:
        libusb_device_handle *dev_handle;
        libusb_endpoint_descriptor _out{};
        libusb_endpoint_descriptor _in{};

    public:
        UsbContext(uint16_t vid, uint16_t pid);
        ~UsbContext();
        int read(unsigned char *data, int length, unsigned int timeout = 0);
        void write(const unsigned char *data, int length, unsigned int timeout = 0);
};



#endif //USBCONTEXT_H

My class file:
#include "../header/UsbContext.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

UsbContext::UsbContext(const uint16_t vid, const uint16_t pid) {
    libusb_context *ctx = nullptr;
    int result = libusb_init(&ctx);
    if (result < 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to initialize libusb");
    }

    dev_handle = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(ctx, vid, pid);
    if (!dev_handle) {
        libusb_exit(ctx);
        throw std::runtime_error("Device not found");
    }

    libusb_reset_device(dev_handle);
    result = libusb_set_configuration(dev_handle, 1);
    if (result < 0) {
        libusb_close(dev_handle);
        libusb_exit(ctx);
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to set configuration");
    }

    result = libusb_claim_interface(dev_handle, 0);
    if (result < 0) {
        libusb_close(dev_handle);
        libusb_exit(ctx);
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to claim interface");
    }

    // Finding the OUT and IN endpoints
    libusb_config_descriptor *config;
    result = libusb_get_active_config_descriptor(libusb_get_device(dev_handle), &config);
    if (result < 0) {
        libusb_close(dev_handle);
        libusb_exit(ctx);
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to get configuration descriptor");
    }

    const libusb_interface *interface = &config->interface[0];
    const libusb_interface_descriptor *interface_desc = &interface->altsetting[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < interface_desc->bNumEndpoints; ++i) {
        const libusb_endpoint_descriptor *ep = &interface_desc->endpoint[i];
        if ((ep->bEndpointAddress & LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_DIR_MASK) == LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_OUT) {
            _out = *ep;
        } else if ((ep->bEndpointAddress & LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_DIR_MASK) == LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_IN) {
            _in = *ep;
        }
    }

    if (!_out.bEndpointAddress) {
        libusb_close(dev_handle);
        libusb_exit(ctx);
        throw std::runtime_error("Output endpoint not found");
    }
    if (!_in.bEndpointAddress) {
        libusb_close(dev_handle);
        libusb_exit(ctx);
        throw std::runtime_error("Input endpoint not found");
    }

    libusb_free_config_descriptor(config);
}

UsbContext::~UsbContext() {
    libusb_close(dev_handle);
    libusb_exit(nullptr);
}

int UsbContext::read(unsigned char *data, const int length, const unsigned int timeout) {
    int transferred;
    if (libusb_bulk_transfer(dev_handle, _in.bEndpointAddress, data, length, &transferred, timeout) < 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Read failed");
    }
    return transferred;
}

void UsbContext::write(const unsigned char *data, const int length, const unsigned int timeout) {
    int transferred;
    if (libusb_bulk_transfer(dev_handle, _out.bEndpointAddress, const_cast<unsigned char *>(data), length, &transferred, timeout) < 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Write failed");
    }
}

The other class is for the logic of my project:
My header file:
#ifndef COMMAND_H
#define COMMAND_H
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include "UsbContext.h"

class Command {
private:
    uint32_t BUFFER_SEGMENT_DATA_SIZE = 0x100000;
    std::unique_ptr<UsbContext> context; // Change to unique_ptr

public:
    Command();
    ~Command() = default; // Destructor is defaulted since it's not doing anything special.
    void process_exit_command();
    std::map<std::string, std::string> process_list_command(std::string& work_dir_path);
    void poll_commands(std::string& work_dir_path);
    void process_file_range_command(uint32_t data_size, std::string& work_dir_path, std::map<std::string, std::string>* cache = nullptr);

    std::unique_ptr<UsbContext> connect_to_switch();
};

#endif //COMMAND_H

My class file:
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>  // for std::memcpy
#include <vector>
#include <thread>      // for sleep_for
#include <chrono>      // for seconds
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>
#include "../header/UsbContext.h"
#include "../header/Command.h"
#include "../enums/CommandId.h"
#include "../enums/CommandType.h"

Command::Command() : context(connect_to_switch()) {
    // Now context is a unique_ptr and the UsbContext's lifetime is managed
}

// Exit command processing
void Command::process_exit_command() {
    std::cout << "Exit" << std::endl;
    std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(16);
    std::memcpy(buffer.data(), "DBI0", 4);  // Magic string 'DBI0'
    constexpr auto cmd_type = static_cast<uint32_t>(CommandType::RESPONSE);
    constexpr auto cmd_id = static_cast<uint32_t>(CommandID::EXIT);
    constexpr auto data_size = 0;
    std::memcpy(buffer.data() + 4, &cmd_type, sizeof(cmd_type));
    std::memcpy(buffer.data() + 8, &cmd_id, sizeof(cmd_id));
    std::memcpy(buffer.data() + 12, &data_size, sizeof(data_size));
    context->write(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
    exit(0);  // Exit after processing
}

// List command processing
std::map<std::string, std::string> Command::process_list_command(std::string& work_dir_path) {
    std::cout << "Get list" << std::endl;
    std::map<std::string, std::string> cached_titles;

    // Traverse directory and collect files
    for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(work_dir_path)) {
        if (entry.is_regular_file()) {
            std::string filename = entry.path().filename().string();
            if (filename.size() >= 4) {
                std::string extension = filename.substr(filename.size() - 4);
                if (extension == ".nsp" || extension == ".nsz" || extension == ".xci") {
                    std::cout << "\tFound file: " << filename << std::endl;
                    cached_titles[filename] = entry.path().string();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Prepare list of file names
    std::string nsp_path_list;
    for (const auto& title : cached_titles) {
        nsp_path_list += title.first + "\n";
    }

    const std::vector<uint8_t> nsp_path_list_bytes(nsp_path_list.begin(), nsp_path_list.end());
    uint32_t nsp_path_list_len = nsp_path_list_bytes.size();

    // Send header
    std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(16);
    std::memcpy(buffer.data(), "DBI0", 4);  // Magic string 'DBI0'
    constexpr auto  cmd_type = static_cast<uint32_t>(CommandType::RESPONSE);
    constexpr auto  cmd_id = static_cast<uint32_t>(CommandID::LIST);
    std::memcpy(buffer.data() + 4, &cmd_type, sizeof(cmd_type));
    std::memcpy(buffer.data() + 8, &cmd_id, sizeof(cmd_id));
    std::memcpy(buffer.data() + 12, &nsp_path_list_len, sizeof(nsp_path_list_len));
    context->write(buffer.data(), buffer.size());

    // Read acknowledgment
    std::vector<uint8_t> ack(16);
    context->read(ack.data(), ack.size(), 0);

    uint32_t ack_cmd_type = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&ack[4]);
    uint32_t ack_cmd_id = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&ack[8]);
    uint32_t ack_data_size = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&ack[12]);

    std::cout << "Cmd Type: " << ack_cmd_type
              << ", Command ID: " << ack_cmd_id
              << ", Data Size: " << ack_data_size << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Ack received" << std::endl;

    // Send file names list
    context->write(nsp_path_list_bytes.data(), nsp_path_list_bytes.size());

    return cached_titles;
}

void Command::process_file_range_command(uint32_t data_size, std::string& work_dir_path, std::map<std::string, std::string>* cache) {
    std::cout << "File range" << std::endl;

    // Send command to context
    std::vector<uint8_t> write_buffer(16);
    std::memcpy(write_buffer.data(), "DBI0", 4);  // Magic string 'DBI0'
    auto cmd_type = static_cast<uint32_t>(CommandType::ACK);
    auto cmd_id = static_cast<uint32_t>(CommandID::FILE_RANGE);

    std::memcpy(write_buffer.data() + 4, &cmd_type, sizeof(cmd_type));
    std::memcpy(write_buffer.data() + 8, &cmd_id, sizeof(cmd_id));
    std::memcpy(write_buffer.data() + 12, &data_size, sizeof(data_size));

    context->write(write_buffer.data(), write_buffer.size());

    // Read file range header from context
    std::vector<uint8_t> file_range_header(data_size);
    context->read(file_range_header.data(), file_range_header.size(), 0);

    // Extract values from header
    uint32_t range_size = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(file_range_header.data());
    uint64_t range_offset = *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(file_range_header.data() + 4);
    uint32_t nsp_name_len = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(file_range_header.data() + 12);

    // Extract nsp_name and process cache
    std::string nsp_name(file_range_header.begin() + 16, file_range_header.end());

    if (cache) {
        auto it = cache->find(nsp_name);
        if (it != cache->end()) {
            nsp_name = it->second;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Range Size: " << range_size
              << ", Range Offset: " << range_offset
              << ", Name len: " << nsp_name_len
              << ", Name: " << nsp_name << std::endl;

    // Prepare response and send it
    std::vector<uint8_t> response_bytes(16);
    std::memcpy(response_bytes.data(), "DBI0", 4);  // Magic string 'DBI0'
    cmd_type = static_cast<uint32_t>(CommandType::RESPONSE);

    std::memcpy(response_bytes.data() + 4, &cmd_type, sizeof(cmd_type));
    std::memcpy(response_bytes.data() + 8, &cmd_id, sizeof(cmd_id));
    std::memcpy(response_bytes.data() + 12, &range_size, sizeof(range_size));

    context->write(response_bytes.data(), response_bytes.size());

    // Read acknowledgment from context
    std::vector<uint8_t> ack(16);
    context->read(ack.data(), ack.size(), 0);

    cmd_type = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&ack[4]);
    cmd_id = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&ack[8]);
    data_size = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&ack[12]);

    std::cout << "Cmd Type: " << cmd_type
              << ", Command id: " << cmd_id
              << ", Data size: " << data_size << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Ack" << std::endl;

    std::string nsp_path = work_dir_path + nsp_name;
    if (!std::filesystem::exists(nsp_path)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("File does not exist: " + nsp_path);
    }

    // Open the file and write its contents to context
    std::ifstream file(nsp_path, std::ios::binary);
    if (!file) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to open file: " + nsp_name);
    }

    file.seekg(range_offset);

    uint64_t curr_off = 0;
    uint64_t end_off = range_size;
    uint32_t read_size = BUFFER_SEGMENT_DATA_SIZE;

    while (curr_off < end_off) {
        if (curr_off + read_size >= end_off) {
            read_size = static_cast<uint32_t>(end_off - curr_off);
        }

        // Read the data from the file
        std::vector<uint8_t> buf(read_size);
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf.data()), read_size);

        // Write the data to the context
        context->write(buf.data(), read_size);

        curr_off += read_size;
    }
}

void Command::poll_commands(std::string& work_dir_path) {
    std::cout << "Entering command loop" << std::endl;

    while (true) {
        std::vector<uint8_t> cmd_header(16);
        int transferred = context->read(cmd_header.data(), 16, 0);
        if (transferred != 16) continue;

        if (std::memcmp(cmd_header.data(), "DBI0", 4) != 0) continue;

        uint32_t cmd_type = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&cmd_header[4]);
        uint32_t cmd_id = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&cmd_header[8]);
        uint32_t data_size = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&cmd_header[12]);

        std::cout << "Cmd Type: " << cmd_type
                  << ", Command ID: " << cmd_id
                  << ", Data Size: " << data_size << std::endl;

        if (cmd_id == static_cast<uint32_t>(CommandID::EXIT)) {
            process_exit_command();
            break;
        }
        std::map<std::string, std::string> cmd_cache;
        if (cmd_id == static_cast<uint32_t>(CommandID::LIST)) {
           cmd_cache = process_list_command(work_dir_path);
        } else if (cmd_id == static_cast<uint32_t>(CommandID::FILE_RANGE)) {
            process_file_range_command(data_size, work_dir_path, &cmd_cache);
        }else {
            std::cerr << "Unknown command ID: " << cmd_id << std::endl;
            process_exit_command();
        }
    }
}

std::unique_ptr<UsbContext> Command::connect_to_switch() {
    std::unique_ptr<UsbContext> switch_context;
    while (true) {
        try {
            switch_context = std::make_unique<UsbContext>(0x057E, 0x3000);
            break;
        } catch (const std::runtime_error&) {
            std::cout << "Waiting for switch..." << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        }
    }
    return switch_context;
}

I stored my commands in a emus:
#ifndef COMMANDID_H
#define COMMANDID_H

#include <cstdint>  // For fixed-width integer types

// Enum for CommandID
enum class CommandID : uint8_t {
    EXIT = 0,
    LIST_DEPRECATED = 1,
    FILE_RANGE = 2,
    LIST = 3
};

#endif //COMMANDID_H

The command types are store in a different enum:
#ifndef COMMANDTYPE_H
#define COMMANDTYPE_H

#include <cstdint>  // For fixed-width integer types

// Enum for CommandType
enum class CommandType : uint8_t {
    REQUEST = 0,
    RESPONSE = 1,
    ACK = 2
};

#endif //COMMANDTYPE_H

I wanted to know how is the structure: did I split it too much and general information on how I can improve my code.

For those of us who don't know what a DBI (or dpi) backend is supposed to do, could you add an introductory paragraph to explain the motivation?  Thanks.

My libusb knowledge is slightly rusty, but I'll attempt to review this.
The UsbContext class gives me concerns.  The first is the name; it sounds like it might be a C++ wrapper for usb_context but it looks more like a device with a pair of endpoints.

UsbContext owns resources using raw pointers.  Either change dev_handle to be a smart pointer with an appropriate deleter function, or make the class non-copyable by adding
    UsbContext(const UsbContext&) = delete;
    auto operator=(const UsbContext&) = delete;


The UsbContext constructor initialises ctx using usb_init() but just loses that if it succeeds.  I think we actually need to keep ctx around as a member, so we can libusb_exit(ctx) in the destructor.  Certainly libusb_exit(nullptr) looks incorrect.

The cleanup in the constructor is mostly good.  However, we can avoid having to repeat the same cleanup in each throw block by catching and rethrowing at the top level of the function:
UsbContext::UsbContext(const uint16_t vid, const uint16_t pid)
    : dev_handle{nullptr}
{
    libusb_context *ctx = nullptr;
    try {
        int result = libusb_init(&ctx);
        if (result < 0) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to initialize libusb");
        }

        ⋮

        if (!_out.bEndpointAddress) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Output endpoint not found");
        }
        if (!_in.bEndpointAddress) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Input endpoint not found");
        }

        ⋮
    } catch (...) {
        if (dev_handle) { libusb_close(dev_handle); }
        if (ctx) { libusb_exit(ctx); }
        throw;
    }
}


General comments about the rest of the code:

Instead of using full paths to headers such as "../header/UsbContext.h", I think it's better to pass these directories to the compiler as include paths (e.g. gcc -I../header).
We use fixed-width types in the global namespace, but don't include <stdint.h>.  Instead, we should include <cstdint> and use the std-namespace versions such as std::uint8_t.
Whenever we use CommandType or CommandID, we widen them to std::uint32_t.  Perhaps we should use std::uint32_t as their underlying types, then we can use std::to_underlying() rather than a cast?
We std::memcpy() to copy integers into USB structures.  Whilst this works on your target (evidently little-endian, like USB), it will break when you re-use the code for a big-endian target.  Take appropriate action now rather than carrying technical debt.
Most of the output looks better suited to std::clog than std::cout.  And we probably don't need std::endl so much - non-flushing \n will be fine for most of these.
~Command() = default; is better simply omitted.
I don't see where the exceptions from read or write errors are caught.  Since no main() is shown, I have to guess that we catch them there.


Thanks for all the helpful Informations. I did not provided the main class since is is pretty short and yes your right the exceptions get catched there.
